# Split string containing ordered numbers in R

Tags: r, string, split

I have strings like this:

```
"12385402763024590"
```

It contains numbers in alternating ascending and descending order. I would like to split them based on these orders. The output would be:

```
"1238"  "540"  "27"  "630"  "2459" "0"
```

How we can do that in R?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. We appreciate when OP provide the issue at hand, a minimal reproducible example and efforts / attempts tried so far.

Comment: Showing efforts / attempts simply allow us to better tailor our answers to address the specific issue(s) you encountered so far (if any). I'm more than happy to provide insights on the *general* issue but given I don't know what part of the task is more problematic, it's harder to know where to put emphasis. What exactly is the core of your issue ? Is it the string splitting ? The part where you have to compare each value to the previous / next one ? How to create group with such subsets, etc.

Comment: @StevenBeaupré you might want to see my own answer [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38443977/split-string-containing-ordered-numbers-in-r/38447631#38447631)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also pass two vectors to `substring`

```
x <- "12385402763024590"
substring(x, c(1,5,8,10,13,17), c(4,7,9,12,16,17))
[1] "1238" "540"  "27"   "630"  "2459" "0"
```

Maybe?

```
sp1 <- function(x){
   y <- as.numeric(strsplit(x, "")[[1]])
   n <- cumsum(rle(diff(y)<0)$lengths) +1
   substring(x, c(1, n[-length(n)]+1),   n )
}

sp1(x)
[1] "1238" "540"  "27"   "630"  "2459" "0"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using `rleid` from `data.table` package and the `split` function from base R:

```
library(data.table)
strToNum <- as.numeric(strsplit(s, "")[[1]])
# split the string into numeric vectors

sapply(split(strToNum, c(1, rleid(diff(strToNum) > 0))), paste0, collapse = "")
# calculate the rleid for sequence in ascending or descending order and split the vector 
# based on the run length encoding ID. Since the first element will always be classified 
# into the first sequence, we prepend 1 in the resulting rleid.

#      1      2      3      4      5      6 
# "1238"  "540"   "27"  "630" "2459"    "0"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my own solution using base R:

```
f <- function(r, char_s){
    cuts <- c(0, which(diff(r) != 1), length(r))
    sapply(seq_along(tail(cuts,-1)), function(x) 
                  paste0(char_s[r[(cuts[x]+1):cuts[x+1]]],collapse=""))
}

char_s <- strsplit(s, "")[[1]]
dif <- c(1,diff(as.numeric(char_s)))

# ascending orders
f(which(dif>0), char_s)
# [1] "1238" "27"   "2459"

# descending orders
f(which(dif<0), char_s)
# [1] "540" "630" "0"
```

Comment: I had given you plus one for this earlier.

Comment: Or another option is `sub` i.e. `scan(text=sub("(.{4})(.{3})(.{2})(.{3})(.{4})(.)", "\\1,\\2,\\3,\\4,\\5", str1), what = numeric(), sep=",")`