# substract subset of data frame from the same data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a data frame of the following structure:
It could have ana number of rows and columns

```
v<-c("control", NA, 1, 2, 4, "test", NA, 1, 2, 4, "test", NA, 1, 2, 4, "test", NA, 1, 2, 4)
df<- as.data.frame(t(matrix(v, nrow=5, ncol=4)))
colnames(df)<-c("ID", "G1", "G2", "G3", "G4")
df
       ID   G1 G2 G3 G4
1 control <NA>  1  2  4
2    test <NA>  1  2  4
3    test <NA>  1  2  4
4    test <NA>  1  2  4
```

I would like to subtract the rows where ID==control from the other rows, giving me the following result:

```
result
           ID   G1 G2 G3 G4
    1    test <NA>  0  0  0
    2    test <NA>  0  0  0
    3    test <NA>  0  0  0
```

I tried the sweep() function, I tried putting it through for loops, but nothing worked.

It would be amazing if someone could help me.
Thank you!

Comment: What if there are two rows with `control` ?

Comment: Your columns are factor

Comment: So far, I am trying to avoid 2 rows with `control` as it would make subsequent statistics more complicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that there is only a single "control", create a logical index based on the 'control' value ('i1'), subset the 'df' for 'ID' that are not 'control' ('df1'), use `Map` to subtract the columns in the 'df1' from the same columns where 'ID' is 'control' and assign the output to the corresponding columns in 'df1'.

```
i1 <- df$ID=="control"
df1 <- df[!i1,]
df1[3:5] <- Map(`-`, df1[3:5], df[i1,3:5])
df1
#    ID   G1 G2 G3 G4
#2 test <NA>  0  0  0
#3 test <NA>  0  0  0
#4 test <NA>  0  0  0
```

---

Or instead of using `Map` we can replicate to make the lengths equal for both datasets and do the subtraction

```
df1[3:5] <- df1[3:5] - df[i1, 3:5][col(df1[3:5])]
```

#### data

```
df[-(1:2)] <- lapply(df[-(1:2)], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

Comment: btw, how did you know who is voted down your answer?

Comment: @m0h3n  I donno, but `Map` is a valid answer

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, I am getting warning messages: `Warning messages:
1: In Ops.factor(dots[[1L]][[3L]], dots[[2L]][[3L]]) :
  ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
2: In Ops.factor(dots[[1L]][[3L]], dots[[2L]][[3L]]) :
  ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
3: In Ops.factor(dots[[1L]][[3L]], dots[[2L]][[3L]]) :
  ‘-’ not meaningful for factors`  resulting in `NA` is a result of the substraction

Comment: @KevinRoth  If you look at the code under 'data', I already changed it to numeric.

Comment: +1. I'd be also interested to have your answer [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38443977/split-string-containing-ordered-numbers-in-r) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use `sweep` like

```
sweep(df[!df$ID == "control", ][3:5],2,
                         as.numeric(as.vector(df[df$ID == "control", ][3:5])))


#   G2 G3 G4
#2   0  0  0
#3   0  0  0
#4   0  0  0
```

Assuming there is only one row with `ID` as `control`. You can subset the rows which does not have `ID` as `control` and subtract it with the row which has `ID` as control. `as.numeric(as.vector(df[df$ID == "control", ][3:5]))` converts it into a vector to be subtracted.